# Incorrect doxygen formatting on only one line

Tags: formatting, doxygen

The heading at the start of the comment block shown in the C code below is formatted incorrectly in both HTML and PDF output as \verbatim text.

All other Doxygen comments I have in this file work perfectly (they are all VERY similar as the file provides functions that conform to a type).

I have tried removing all preceding Doxygen comments from the file (except the @name) to rule out incorrect block formatting closing, removing the heading spec (#'s) changing the heading text (eg "foo") in case of incorrect characters, removing the later \verbatim block, removing *this* entire comment block itself to see if the problem transferred to the next one, but nothing seems to change!!

How can I get the heading to format correctly?? Thanks.

code:

```
/** # *IDN? - Identification query #
 * This query allows the instrument to identify itself. It responds with a `<`string`>` consisting of four fields
 * separated by commas. The four fields are determined by constants defined in the application
 * specific settings in config.h and appear in the following order:
 * \verbatim MANUF,MODEL,SERIAL,FIRMW \endverbatim
 * See the config.h file description for information on each of these fields.
 *
 * @param   parameters  None
 * @param   query       `*IDN?`
 */
extern int16_t IDN (double * parameters, bool query);
```

### How this looks in PDF:

[image: how it looks in pdf screenshot]

### How this looks in HTML:

[image: how it looks in html screenshot]

**EDIT:** The comments for the OPC function:

```
/** # *OPC - Operation Complete Command. #
 * This command causes the device to set the operation complete bit in the standard event status register when
 * all pending device operations have completed.
 *
 * The query responds with an ASCII "1" when all pending device operations are complete.
 *
 * @param   parameters  None
 * @param   query       `*OPC?`
 */
extern int16_t OPC (double * parameters, bool query);
```

Comment: Seeing the source for the documentation for `OPC` would be useful. Whatever the difference between the comment blocks for `OPC` and `IDN` will be the answer you are looking for. I would guess that you need a new line between the first and second lines of text, but this is just a guess.

Comment: @Chris, ta, added by edit at the bottom of the question there.

Comment: @Toby Which version of doxygen. I placed the 2 code fragments in .h files set EXTRACT_ALL to YES in the default Doxyfile, ran with 1.8.7 on Windows and didn't see a problem.

Comment: @albert v 1.8.4, is there anything in the newer version that is likely to affect this though?

Comment: @Toby Not that I'm aware off in respect to this matter, but with 1.8.4 and the settings as given above I see no problem either.

Comment: What happens if you avoid mixing Markdown and Dox, and use `<h1>`...`</h1>` instead of the hashes?

Comment: @Cheeseminer de nada. Tried removing all formatting from the file (except tables) but still fruitless :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this, though Im still unsure as to the cause.
Basically I rewrote the documentation comment a bit at a time (I was trying to see if  I could isolate any one item that caused it).
I started with a one word comment, when that appeared correctly I slowly added more bits, rebuilding after each addition. I now have the full comment, exactly as before, but now working as intended

Puzzling... maybe doxygen only rebuilt that part after it detected the comment being deleted and started again and that cleared whatever the issue was?? Meh, it's fixed anyway. Thanks for the suggestions.